# Is there a way to translate cin.fail and cin.clear to C programming language?

Tags: c++, c

I used the clear function in C++ before but i don't know how it works in C. 
    I've read somewhere that C isn't aware of the screen and that the clear function does not exist in C. Is there another method of translating this?
   in case the `.clear` and `.fail` functions do not exist:

Final Q: How do you write `cin.fail` and `cin.clear` also `cin.ignore` in C?

```
 int main(){
int n;
cout << "Please enter number shapes to check: ";
cin >> n;

while(cin.fail() || n<1) {
    cout << "Your number of shapes is invalid. " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cout << "Enter the number of shapes to check: ";
    cin >> n;
```

Comment: Just write code to do this same thing in C. You don't need a perfect analog of each function.

Comment: I can only imagine using goto ...@DavidSchwartz

Comment: I don't follow. What would the `goto` do?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Realising I didn't clearly define the function here I have extended and modifed the code, take a look

Answer (score 3):

Look into [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html), and related `ferror`, `clearerr`.

See also [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Notice that [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (so `sscanf`)  returns a count and knows about `%n`

Comment: I will try to understand them. Thanks